# In-rush current limit MOSFET, resistor

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, gsm, inrush-current

I'm using DC/DC converter LTC3112 to supply GSM module. Battery source is about 12V and DC/DC output is 3.7V. Microcontroller logic is 3.3V powered from other DC/DC converter. The application is working fine but I want to limit the in-rush current in new PCB which charges the GSM capacitators using resistor and MOSFET-P as a bypass. The schematic and components values are just a draft. I would like to limit the DC/DC output current to 300mA when MOSFET-P is off and turn it on through microcontroller GPIO to bypass the resistor. The peak current flown through DC/DC and MOSFET is 2A.

I would like to use IRLML6401 as a MOSFET-P but Im not really sure if it will work properly. I'v got IRFML8244 (MOSFET-N) in stock  as well.

1) What is the best way to make such bypass circuit using MOSFETs?

2) Is it possible to make such a design to drive MOSFET from single voltage rail, let's assume I don't have 12V and only 3.7V?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU7va1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: can you modify the DC-DC module's feedback loop to impose this current limit?

Comment: @Jasen - Im not sure how to do it. The DC/DC circuit looks like that one on 25 page: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3112fd.pdf Can you give me any hints on limiting the in-rush current modifing feedback loop?